# I'm not understanding this concept on conditional probability with two continuous random variables.

Tags: probability

I have the following problem and solution:

[image]

By the definition of conditional probability,

$$P[Y < X | X = 1/3] = \frac{P[(Y < x)\cap(X = 1/3)}{P[X = 1/3]}.$$

But since $X$ is a continuous random variable, I would think that the probability of $X$ taking on any one value between $0$ and $1$ is $0$. So I would think that $P[X = 1/3] = 0$.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: +1: Good question.  With continuous random variables you need to look at the marginal distribution $\displaystyle f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, dy$ and then define the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ as $\dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$ when $f_X(x) \not = 0$ and this has most of the properties you would expect, though beware [Borel's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox) about coordinate transformations.